# C# Automapper how to apply some logic to a member

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper to map by data object to domain object. For one of the member, i want to use some parser to the source data and map the extracted data to destination. How can i use some custom logic in Automapper?

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
          .ForMember(dest=>dest.Title, 
                     options=><ApplySomeLogicHere>);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple.  For example. It is some logic to the mapped field . For this example I fill the `dest.Date` which is `WCFDate` type object from field which is simple `DateTime` structure

```
{... }
.ForMember(dest => dest.Date,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var day = Convert.ToInt32(src.Date.Substring(0, 2));
                                var month = Convert.ToInt32(src.Date.Substring(3, 2));
                                var year = Convert.ToInt32(src.Date.Substring(6, 4));

                                return new WcfDate(new DateTime(year, month, day));
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                throw new ArgumentException("Premium date conversion error for date {0}.", src.Date);
                            }
                        }));
```

As You can see. It is simple lamdba expression.

You can create Your own converter. You must implement interface `ITypeConverter<in TSource, out TDestination>` from AutoMapper namespace

Comment: Thanks. Can we have this logic in a separate class and call a method?

Comment: Yes of course.See the doc - > https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

Comment: Getting an error saying A Lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

Comment: Do You use a Resharper what version? What version of AutoMapper You use?

Comment: .ForMember(dest => dest.TITLE,
                               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new
                               {
                                   src.TITLE
                               }));

Comment: src => new { src.TITLE }) change to src => src.TITLE. but if the property of dest and soruce is the same name, you don't need to map this